# Split directory into 3 directories

Tags: files, directory, split

I have a directory containing around 24800 .mp4 files how can I split it into 4 directories containg all the files without keeping the original 24800 files in one directory ? is there any MV/move command to do this?

Comment: Create 4 directories and move one quarter of the files to each one. But, what will be the criterion to move a file to a specific directory. Your question is not clear. And the title is inconsistent with the body. So I vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no system in the file names, allowing you to move parts of the files using wildcards, then I would be using the bash text tools to create a list of the files in a text file:

```
ls > filelist.txt
```

then split it in different parts, then for each part use `sed` to edit each line so it constitutes a move command, e.g.

```
filename.mp3
```

becomes

```
mv "filename.mp3" targetdir
```

These text files can then be sourced at the command line to automatically execute each and every command to move a file to a different folder. If for example such text file is called "part_1", then you can source that file as:

```
. part_1
```

or

```
source part_1
```

Alternatively, you can make such file containing valid commands executable, and execute it. Preferably then, you add a shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) as the first line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `/bin/echo` when you feel the script does what you expect it to do

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

a=(source/*)
for ((b=0, c=$((${#a[@]} / 4)),d=0; b < ${#a[@]}; b+=c)); do
    mkdir -p target/$((++d))
    printf %s\\0 "${a[@]:$b:$c}" | xargs -r -0 /bin/echo mv -t target/$d --
done
```